# Pie chart expressing 18 hours of one context and 6 hours of another - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

Good morning from Australia

I am trying to create an energy budget in a pie chart - basically I would like to make this in R

[image: Energy Budget]

I am wondering if any one has a script or way of doing this in r.

This is my data.

```
**Context   Behaviour   With**  

Absent  *Burst*        2.7      

Absent  **High energy swimming* 1.95    

Absent  *Medium energy swimming*    1.95    

Absent  *Low energy swimming*   8.48    

Absent  *Travel*    0.85    

Absent  *Ascending* 1.20    

Absent  *Descending*    1.41    

Present *Burst* 0.77

Present *High energy swimming*  1.25

Present **Medium energy swimming*   0.75    

Present *Low energy swimming*   1.69    

Present *Travel*    0.26                
 
Present *Ascending* 0.97                

Present *Descending*    0.32
```

I am trying to create one pie chart as in the image using the "with" column where 6 hours (Present context) and 18 hours (absent context) are differentiated but show the same behaviours proportionally.

I really appreciate your help with this.

Thank you :)

Comment: Are you saying that you want to create one pie per Context? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to create a pie that presents both contexts as 18+6=24 hours, they both have the same behaviours but I am wanting to look at them proportionally to each other over a 24 hour period

Comment: I have used facet_wrap(~ Context)+with a pie chart script which creates the two slices but in separate graphs

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
my_data %>%
  group_by(Context) %>%
  summarise(time = sum(With)) %>%
  mutate(share = time/sum(time)) %>%
  mutate(round_hr = paste(round(share * 24, 0), " h")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(1, share, fill = Context)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = round_hr), color = "white", size = 6,
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Data, formatted for use:

```
my_data <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
           Context = c("Absent","Absent","Absent",
                       "Absent","Absent","Absent","Absent","Present",
                       "Present","Present","Present","Present","Present","Present"),
         Behaviour = c("*Burst*",
                       "**High energy swimming*","*Medium energy swimming*",
                       "*Low energy swimming*","*Travel*","*Ascending*","*Descending*","*Burst*",
                       "*High energy swimming*","**Medium energy swimming*",
                       "*Low energy swimming*","*Travel*","*Ascending*",
                       "*Descending*"),
              With = c(2.7,1.95,1.95,8.48,0.85,
                       1.2,1.41,0.77,1.25,0.75,1.69,0.26,0.97,0.32)
)
```